# How to transfer sol from the account owned by BPF Upgradable Loader

Tags: bpf

https://solscan.io/account/5S1ndrAdfze7vttBsPsp3eugjMr5U8BSvfqFSEJ4D2Eg

I have secret key of this account but I can't transfer sol.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This account is completely empty, so *anyone* can write into it and take it over.

Your best bet is to try to write any program data into it and claim it for yourself! I don't want to execute the command for fear of taking your account, but you should be able to do something like:

```
solana program write-buffer --buffer <BUFFER_KEYPAIR> <SOME_PROGRAM.SO>
```

And then close it using:

```
solana program close <BUFFER_KEYPAIR>
```