# Solana Account owner change to BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111

Tags: wallet, systemprogram, owner, bpf

My wallet have been changed Assigned Program Id from System program to BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111, how can I reassign to system program? Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mind sharing the transaction? Its more likely that it was transferred to a different program than BPFLoaderUpgradeab1e11111111111111111111111. There were some scam programs like this in the past. If ownership was transferred to another program there is no way to reassign it without using that program itself. Solandy made a recovery tool which can recover some of these funds.

Use at your own risk though!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TLF_Qi154k&ab_channel=Solandy%5Bsolandy.sol%5D

https://solana-asset-recovery.vercel.app/transactions

If you actually transferred the ownership to the BPFLoader program somehow, then you should add some data to it and claim it for yourself asap.
https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/11552/712

Comment: Appreciate it, i will check the tool. I think i make a wrong solana command like 'solana deploy program' that change owner account

Comment: I have tried the tool you told, but it seems not working. It shows non-based58 character error, I have encoded the payload to base58 but still the same error

Comment: Sorry i cant help with the tool sadly. I havent tried it nor red the code.

Comment: If you actually transferred the ownership to the BPFLoader program somehow, then you should add some data to it and claim it for yourself asap. https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/11552/712

Comment: Oh I think I understand how to reassign account back, I will try it and update the solution. Thanks a lot